# ASP Compare server variable with DB recordset

Tags: asp-classic, recordset, request.servervariables

I'm new to this old scripting language but it's all we have right now. I'm trying to get this code work.

I would like to compare USERID servervariable with the same USERID from a recordset, then if true it will redirect the name of that USERID.

```
<%

Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=I:\storyData.mdb" 

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.Open "SELECT USERIDFROM preprod", conn

strName = "John"
strNo = "This is not you"

If Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USERID") = (rs.Fields.Item("USERID").Value) Then

Response.Redirect("story.html?" & "name=" & strName)

Else

Response.Redirect("story.html?" & "name=" & strNo)

End If

%>
```

I hope this makes any sense. It seems simple but can't get it to work.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

what "doesn't" work?

looking at your code, it seems you're only checking the the first record of your query. I think you want to do something like this:

```
<%

Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=I:\storyData.mdb" 

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.Open "SELECT count( USERID ) FROM preprod where userID = " & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USERID"), conn

strName = "John"
strNo = "This is not you"

if CInt( rs( 0 ) ) > 0 then

    Response.Redirect("story.html?" & "name=" & strName)
Else

    Response.Redirect("story.html?" & "name=" & strNo)

End If

%>
```

this code does a count of userIDs in your table and if there are more than 1, it'll do the redirect properly. A lot more efficient this way.

Comment: I don't know who voted this answer down, but on the surface, this seems like a better answer to the OP by Dax. Dax, you're missing any form of narrowing down or looping through. As @Josh has intimated, you're only checking against the first returned row in the record set. You need a movenext or to narrow the result set down through the query.

Comment: @Mark Seems a reasonable enough answer. I will say that directly injecting the header instead of using a parameterised query is fraught with problems so it might perhaps be that.

Comment: @Lankymart - true but that's outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: @JoshMontgomery that’s strange, didn’t even notice there was a question. As for scope, any asp code that interacts with the db layer and takes values from an external source *(querystring, form post, headers etc.)* should be parameterised using the `ADODB.Command` object, which is about as on “scope” as you can get for this post.

Comment: Remembering of course, we're civilised, mature people... I agree that there seems to be a lack of direct question. And I agree that not performing SOME sort of procedure on the input is a terrible idea. That said, we're here to help Dax, not criticise his questioning ability.

Comment: @Mark actually we are here to help everyone which requires clear well defined questions *(a lot of people misunderstand that concept)*. Not just, i've got this piece of code...make it work. We are here to critique question and answers to maintain a degree of quality, how else will people learn to write clear succinct useful questions that the whole community can benefit from. Great starting points; [ask] and providing [mcve].

Comment: Fair enough. I see what you're saying. :)

Comment: No need to use COUNT() function, it's waste of resources. Just do a `Select * From ...` then check for EOF. If true it means there's no such record, otherwise it means the record exists.

Comment: @LankyMart - that's strange, I thought people who post on SO were looking for help, therefore the whole "question" thingy...also, I disagree...Yes, parameterized queries SHOULD be in place, but that requires educating the OP, perhaps providing them with examples, and walking them through that process with their own code, deciding on how to update their code structures, run tests until all of the bugs are worked out, then do a release...THEN we work on the original issue of a redirect not working as intended? you have a funny def of scope...

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I respectfully disagree. What if that table has millions of users in it? I think using a sql function that's been optimized over and over again during its existence is more efficient than code that hasn't been updated in ~ twenty years?

Comment: @JoshMontgomery the "scope" of the problem includes talking to a database regardless of whether it is just to define a redirect. We should also mention they are using Microsoft Access for web development, is the database secured, is it stored outside of the scope of the website. They really should be looking at using an RMDBS that is up to the task, like SQL Server Express Edition which is completely free. There is no reason for using an Access database for web development in 2018, there just isn't.

Comment: @JoshMontgomery That's correct people do come here looking for help, there is nothing wrong with that. There are a lot of useful questions and answers already on [so]. The main issue is people who arrive here ask poorly structured questions that demands you fix their poorly written code then get upset when you try pointing them to [ask] and go off into the web to rant about the poisionous community known as StackOverflow.

Comment: @Lankymart - I disagree. Talking to the DB is part of the process for defining their redirect, but that part is working. The part that is NOT working is the logic to process that data. Again, should PQ be used? IMO, yes, but I don't know everything about the OP's situation. Are they working for a small company where resources are stretched thin? Do they have any experience with sql server? if not, are they in the position to learn it? these are all relevant questions but are not in the scope of their problem.

Comment: I know I'm not the only one on SO that comes on here with 5-10 minutes to spare and want to help out. If I took your approach and rewrote everybody's app, or suggested how to, I would never be able to help anyone!